Why does the Fourier series of a function $h$ not converge uniformly to $h$ itself?
Let $L>0$, and $\hat{f}:[-L,L)\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by
$$\hat{f}(x) = \begin{cases}0, &x\in[-L,0) \\\frac{x}{L\vphantom{0}}, &x\in[0,L)\end{cases}$$
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the $2L$-periodic extension of $\hat{f}$, i.e. $f$ is a $2L$-periodic function, and for $x\in[-L,L)$ we have $f(x)=\hat{f}(x)$.
Let $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $h(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$.
I have already proven that the Fourier series of $h$ is equal to
$$\frac{1}{2}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4}{(2k+1)^2\pi^2}\cos\bigg(\frac{(2k+1)\pi x}{L}\bigg)$$
I am now asked to prove that the Fourier series of $h$ converges uniformly, but not to $h$.
I observed that the Fourier coefficients are absolutely summable and therefore the Fourier series converges uniformly to the pointwise limit of the Fourier series. I was under the assumption that since $h$ is a continuous function, the pointwise limit of the Fourier series corresponds to $h$ itself. As a result, I thought that the Fourier series of $h$ thus converges uniformly to $h$ itself. Which mistake am I making in my thought process?

If I understand correctly, then f(x) is a modification of the sawtooth function. With $h(x) = f(x) + f(-x)$, h(x) is a triangular pulse with $h(x) = \frac{|x|}{L}$ for $x \in [-L,+L]$.

I note that the average value of $\hat{f}$ is $1/4$, so the leading "$1/2$" for your series is suspect, perhaps a typo' or perhaps is strong evidence of convergence to something other than $f$.

I thought about this, and expected the Fourier series of $f$ at $x=L$ to converge pointwise to $\frac{1}{2}(f(L-)+f(L+))=\frac{1}{2}(1+0)=\frac{1}{2}$. Consequently, I expected the pointwise limit at $x=L$ of the Fourier series of $f(x)+f(-x)$ to converge to $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$, which would correspond with $h(L)=1$. However, I am not sure if this is mathematically sound as I have not learned about any theory involving the pointwise limit of the sum of two Fourier series.

@EricTowers the leading term of the Fourier series of $f$ is indeed $\frac{1}{4}$ and $h(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$, so in the Fourier series of $h$ we get a leading term of $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Unless I misread, $h(L)=0$ while $h(L^-)=\frac{1}{2}$, no?

I think many people are confusing $f$ with $h$. Note that $f$ is the extension of $\hat{f}$, while $h$ is defined as $h(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$. The original exercise has more subquestions and I only took out the relevant information but did not simplify as to not make any mistakes in the question itself.

@Wouter Sorry, you're correct that I mistook $f$ and $h$. But looking carefully at the definition, I believe you'll find that $h(L) = f(L) + f(-L) = f(-L) + f(-L) = 0 + 0 = 0$. So if the Fourier series converges to $L$ at $x = L$, but $h(L) = 0$...

@MartianInvader Ahhh, so at $x=L$ the Fourier series converges pointwise to $1$, while $h(L)=0$ and thus it does not converge uniformly to $h$?

@Wouter : D'oh.  Two copies of the average -- it's been long enough I forgot that detail.  Thanks for reminding me.

If you understand that the series converges to the midpoint of a jump discontinuity, then you know that uniform convergence in a neighborhood around there isn't going to happen...

If I understand correctly, then $f(x)$ is a modification of the sawtooth function.
$$\hat{f}(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0 & x \in [-L,0) \\ \frac{x}{L} & x \in [0,L) \end{matrix}\right.$$.
$$\hat{f}(-x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{-x}{L} & x \in (-L,0] \\ 0 & x \in (0,L] \end{matrix}\right.$$.
With $h(x) = f(x) + f(-x)$, $h(x)$ is a triangular pulse with
$$\hat{h}(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{|x|}{L} & x \in (-L,L) \\ 0 & x \in \{-L,L\}  \end{matrix}\right.$$.
Since the function $h(x)$ is symmetrical, $b_n = 0$. For $a_0$ we get:
\begin{align}
a_0 &= \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{+L} h(x) \ \text{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^0 -\frac{x}{L} \ \text{d}x + \frac{1}{L} \int_0^{+L} \frac{x}{L} \ \text{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1
\end{align}
For $a_n$ we get:
\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{+L} h(x)\,\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right) \ \text{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^0 -\frac{x}{L}\,\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right) \ \text{d}x + \frac{1}{L} \int_0^{+L} \frac{x}{L}\,\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right) \ \text{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}\left(n\pi\,\sin{n\pi} + \cos{n\pi} - 1\right) + \frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}\left(n\pi\,\sin{n\pi} + \cos{n\pi} - 1\right) \\
&= \frac{2}{n^2\pi^2}\left((-1)^n-1\right)
\end{align}
So the Fourier Series is:
\begin{align}
h_\text{F}(x) &= \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2\pi^2} ((-1)^n - 1) \cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{4}{(2k+1)^2\pi^2} \cos\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{L}x\right) \\
\end{align}
The problem is that $h(x)$ is not continuous for $x=(2j+1)L$. The following applies:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow (2j+1)L} h(x) &= 1, \hspace{30pt} &h((2j+1)L) = 0 \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow (2j+1)L} h_\text{F}(x) &= 1, \hspace{30pt} &h_\text{F}((2j+1)L) = 1
\end{align}

The function $h(x)$ is $2L$-periodic and satisfies $h(x)={|x|\over L} $ for $|x|<L$ and $h(L)=0.$ Consider the $2L$-periodic function $g(x)={|x|\over L}$ for $|x|\le L.$ Then $g(x)$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition $|g(t)-g(s)|\le |t-s|.$ Moreover $g(x)=h(x)$ for $x\neq nL.$ Hence the Fourier series of $g$ and $h$ coincide. The Fourier series of $g$, due to the Lipschitz condition, tends uniformly to $g.$ Hence it does not converge to $h$ as $h(L)\neq g(L).$ For the particular function $h(x)$ the Fourier series can be calculated explicitly, as was done in OP and observed that the coefficients are absolutely summable, which implies the uniform convergence.
